# read the Xen Source code

Tags: migration, virtualization, xen

i want to modify the xen(hypervisor) migration code. For that purpose i want to read out and understand the source code in terms of control flow, linkage and usage of different code segments. mainly i want to focus on migration code in xen's source code. but i can't understand by watching out the source code, actually i didn't find some accurate document describing the code in detail. And without such help its too difficult to understand such a large code.

please help me how to read the xen code and modify(add some extra code) the same.

Comment: Start [here](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenSourceCode?highlight=%28sourcecode%29)

Answer (score 1):

There's really no document that can substitute reading the source code, unfortunately. Xen development happens at breakneck speed.

The closest thing to in-depth documentation is a book called "The Definitive Guide to the Xen Hypervisor" by David Chisnall, it's out there if you look for it. But it's pretty outdated.

Your best bet is to just dive into the code, and ask questions on the xen-devel mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the sourcecode page in the [wiki](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenSourceCode.html).